# The graph of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ cuts the $x$-axis where $x=2$ and at an angle of $45$°.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

The graph of 
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ 
cuts the $x$-axis where $x=2$ and at an angle of $45$°.
It cuts the $y$-axis at $y=6$ 
and the equation of the tangent at this point is 
$5x+y=6$.

Find $a, b, c, d$.

Hi, Can anyone help me with this question above.

Thanks.

Comment: Alas, I cannot provide an answer because you specify that the cubic passes through $(0,6)$, which is inconsistent with the tangent through that point having the equation $5x+y=4$.

Answer (score 0):

When it says it cuts the $x$ axis at $x=2$ you know the point $(2,0)$ is on the graph.  The statement about cutting the $y$ axis gives you one more point on the curve.  The angle $45^\circ$ says the slope of the tangent at that point is (what?), so take the derivative and set it equal to that value at the point $(2,0)$  Similarly the equation of the tangent at the $y$ axis cut gives you one more equation.  You should have four equations in four unknowns:  $a,b,c,d$ to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$.

Since $f$ cuts the $x$ axis at $2$,
$$ f(2) = 8a + 4b + 2c + d = 0
$$
Since that is with an angle of $45$ degrees,
$$ 12 a + 4b + 2c = f'(2) = \tan 45^\circ = 1
$$

Since $f$ cuts the $y$ axis at $y = 6$, $$d = f(0) = 6$$. The line $5x + y = 4$ has slope $-5$, so you can also conclude that $$c = f'(0) = -5$$.

Therefore, you have the four equations
$$\begin{cases}
8a + 4b + 2c + d &= 0 \\
12a + 4b + 2c &= 1 \\
d &= 6\\
c &= -5
\end{cases}$$
Solving them gives you the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

- $f(2) = 0$
- $f(x) = a(x-2)(x-u)(x-v)$
- $f'(x) = a(x-u)(x-v) + a(x-2)(x-v) + a(x-2)(x-u)$
- $f'(2) = 1$
- - $ a(2-u)(2-v) = 1$
- - $ 4a - 2au -2av + auv = 1$
- $f(0) = 6$
- - $-2auv = 6$
- - $ auv = -3$
- $f'(0) = -5$
- - $auv + 2av + 2au = -5$
- - $-3 + 2av + 2au = -5$
- - $ 2av + 2au = -2$
- $ 4a - 2au -2av + auv = 1$
- - $ 4a + 2 - 3 = 1$
- - $a = \dfrac 12$
- $uv = -6$
- $ u + v = -2$
- - $(x-u)(x-v) = x^2 + 2x - 6$
- $f(x) = a(x-2)(x-u)(x-v)$
- - $f(x) = \dfrac 12(x-2)(x^2 + 2x - 6)$
- - $f(x) = \dfrac 12x^3 - 5x + 6$

\begin{align}
    a &= \dfrac 12\\
    b &= 0 \\
    c &= -5\\
    d &= 6
\end{align}